# Access variable between pipeline jobs

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-tasks, azure-yaml-pipelines

I have a yaml which calls a template to perform a few tasks one of which is to deploy azure infrastructure and another is to run a powershell script to parse output variables.

How do I access these variables in a different job within the yaml?

```
jobs:
  - deployment: Dep1
    displayName: MyDep1
    pool:
      name:
    variables:
      //some variables
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - download: current
            artifact: drop
          - task: //ignore
           
          - template: mytemplatelocation
            parameters:
              //all template parameters that also runs powershell script to parse output variables

          - task: Powershell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: 'Write-Host "$(myVariable)'
```

Powershell task is able to print the variable value

But I have another job in this pipeline as below:

```
- deployment: Dep2
    displayName: MyDep2
    dependsOn: [Dep1]
    pool:
      name: 
    variables: 
      actualVarToUse: $[ dependencies.Dep1.outputs['myVariable'] ]
      actualVarToUseDup: $[dependencies.Dep1.outputs['TaskNameFromTemplate.myVariable']]    
    strategy:
     runOnce:
       deploy:
        steps:
        - download: current
          artifact: check
        - script: echo $(actualVarToUse) //does not work
        - task: Powershell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: 'Write-Host "$(actualVarToUse)"' //does not work
        - task: Powershell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: 'Write-Host "$(actualVarToUseDup)"' //does not work
        - task: Powershell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: 'Write-Host $[dependencies.Dep1.outputs[myVariable]]' //does not work
```

Please suggest?

Edit 1:

Template yml

```
parameters:
  - name: outputVariableName
    displayName: ''
    type: string
    default: 'outputvar'
  
steps:
- checkout: git://Scripts
  path: 'Scripts'
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'Deploy Azure Infra'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 
    subscriptionId: 
    resourceGroupName: 
    location: 
    csmFile: 
    csmParametersFile: 
    deploymentMode: 
    deploymentOutputs: ${{ parameters.outputVariableName}}

- task: PowerShell@2
  name: 'Create_${{ parameters.outputVariableName}}'
  displayName: ''  
  inputs:
    targetType: 
    filePath: 
    arguments:
```

Script which is called above

```
param(    
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)][string]$ARMOutput
)

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web.Extensions
$JS = New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer

$data = $JS.DeserializeObject($ARMOutput)

$data.GetEnumerator() | foreach {
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myvar-$($_.key);]$($_.value.value)"   
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myvar-$($_.key);isOutput=true;]$($_.value.value)"   
    Write-Host "Added variable: myvar-$($_.key)"
}
```

The above script creates multiple properties assume myvar-varone, myvar-vartwo

```
- task: Powershell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: 'Write-Host "$(myvar-varone) $(myvar-vartwo)"'
```

The above successfully prints the values now can you please tell me how do I get these in another job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you would like to access variable across jobs, please fix as below:

1. Make sure to use `isoutput=true` when you set the variable under `steps`. In my sample, i set variable in template.
   [image]

```
parameters:
- name: 'var'  # defaults for any parameters that aren't specified
  type: string

steps:
- pwsh: Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVariable;isoutput=true]${{ parameters.var }}"
  name: setvarStep
```

PS: if you `don't` set variable in template, in `Dep1` job, you need to set variable with isoutput=true so the variable can be used in next job.

2. In the main yaml, to invoke the variable in **same job**, you need to add `stepname` before variable, like `$(setvarStep.myVariable)`.
3. In the Next Dep2 job, **be sure to prefix the job name to the output variables of a deployment job**. In this case, the job name is `Dep1`.

The Main Yaml:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
  - deployment: Dep1
    displayName: MyDep1
    variables:
      - name: var1
        value: var1value
    environment: Dep1
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - template: template/azure-devops-template1.yml
            parameters:
              var: "testvar value"
          
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: 'Write-Host $(setvarStep.myVariable)'


  - deployment: Dep2
    displayName: MyDep2
    dependsOn: [Dep1]
    environment: Dep2
    variables: 
      VartoUse: $[ dependencies.Dep1.outputs['Dep1.setvarStep.myVariable'] ]
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: Powershell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: 'Write-Host "$(VartoUse)"'
```

Check value in pipeline:
[image]

More details you can refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable) below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I am fairly new to this let me edit my question to add the template part to provide more clarity.

Comment: Thanks for your update! You are setting variable in task `'Create_${{ parameters.outputVariableName}}'`,  I don't know the parameter value here. But please firstly check in **same job Dep1**, output the variable value with format like `$(taskname.myVariable)`, this can check if the variable is setting properly with `isOutput=true`.  Is the variable value correct? If it is, please check the variable in next job `Dep2`, make sure you used the taskname as my sample ($[ dependencies.Dep1.outputs['Dep1.setvarStep.myVariable'] ])above.

Comment: It is a parameter and its default value (outputvar) is being set in the same template yaml

Comment: In Dep1 job I can access the value with the last powershell task that I have in my question with Write host: $(myvar-varone) which is getting created in script which template last task calls

Comment: You have defined parameter in yaml, but not sure if you transfer the value in main yaml which will override it. Please remove the parameter in the task name to keep it simple for troubleshooting, then output `$(taskname.myVariable)` in main yaml, is it working?

Comment: Ok I will try and update. However I do have one question: If I am able to access $(myvar-varone) in main yaml, can I set its value to another variable in this job and access in the next job? If yes, how? I understand it is not clean but till I try your suggestion of not using a parameter value in task name I wanted to know this.

Comment: Yes, if $(myvar-varone) works fine in main yaml, you can `also` use logging command to define it with `new variable name` with `isOutput=true`, the value is `$(myvar-varone)`, so that the `new` variable can be accessed in next job.  But since you have already defined in template(you have two `setvarible` commands), it's same as you defined in main yaml.

Comment: Hi @Lucky, may i know if there's any update? Please make sure $(taskname.myVariable) ouput is working in your first job, it validates the variable setting(isOutput=true). You can refer to the doc i shared above for the details. Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Yes your suggestion worked, thanks a lot. I am sorry I could not login for a few days  due to some personal challenge and I checked today

Comment: Never mind, glad to know it helps!